# Lot of memory leaks in soap (sap , obiee sfdc ) using JavaEE aplication .

Tags: multithreading, spring, jakarta-ee, soap, memory-leaks

Iam working on a project which integrates various bi systems (sap , obiee, sfdc reports & dashboard ) and few other .

My application is develop on java , Spring , hibernate , and axis soap. I use many wsdl. generated soaps to integrate the external system to my system

I find that my application eats more of memory. it very quickly throws perm germ exceptions.

```
    `Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/mybi_090414] has started
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-43] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@ea7d85f]) and a value of type [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@2d6e4c7d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@ea7d85f]) and a value of type [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@245fb9d8]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@ea7d85f]) and a value of type [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@8a22690]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@ea7d85f]) and a value of type [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@4d91bc5d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/mybi_090414] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@ea7d85f]) and a value of type [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@1ae5a574]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Apr 14, 2014 6:51:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Cloudeeva work\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\mybi_090414\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:448)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:896)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:945)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.configure(ConfigureListener.java:426)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:24 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 15, 2014 1:26:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mybi_090414]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1234)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:763)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
`
```

And iam unable to find a way to handle these memory leaks.

My questions does sound very open ended. But , I have no information on what and where the things are going wrong .

I feel i miss the knowledge of :
 1. Finding the source of these memory leaks.
 2. Proper way to handle these leaks.
 3. Proper handling of soap call , mainly to handle the threads created by these calls.

and may be many other.

I see number of threads (with names : Timer-1 , 2 .. ) getting created in my application which last for longer and when i try to restart the application all these threads leads to memory leaks.

I welcome any links , pointers , or suggestions to find , handle memory leaks. Please do let me know if any miss any basics due which memory leaks are accorded .

Note

Comment: Don't do hot redeploys. Stop, deploy, start... Judging from the stacktrace you are doing hot-redeploys.

Comment: Thanks for quick replay.you point to "hot redeployment" realy helped me understand the issue bit more.
I just came across a blog, [Classloader leaks: the dreaded "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" exception](http://frankkieviet.blogspot.in/2006/10/classloader-leaks-dreaded-permgen-space.html) & [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660437/what-makes-hot-deployment-a-hard-problem) after going through these i feel that we can do something in my code to postponed the permgen exceptions. 

I have question, is this memory leaks directly related to number of soap call iam making?