# Hot deploy not working with IntelliJ IDEA and Wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly-8

I'm currently trying to set up `hot deployment` on `Wildfly 8.2.0` in `IntelliJ IDEA 14`.

My settings are:

`Wildfly 8.2.0`: `Deployment scanners` enabled, `Auto-deploy Zipped` and `Auto-deploy Exploded` set to true and `scan interval` is set to 2000

`IntelliJ IDEA 14`: `On update action` and `On frame deactivation` both set to Update classes and resources

But it's still not working. I have to redeploy the application to update the java files.

Edit:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => {"scanner" => {"default" => {
        "auto-deploy-exploded" => true,
        "auto-deploy-xml" => true,
        "auto-deploy-zipped" => true,
        "deployment-timeout" => 600,
        "path" => "deployments",
        "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir",
        "runtime-failure-causes-rollback" => false,
        "scan-enabled" => true,
        "scan-interval" => 2000
    }}}
```

Comment: Can you please show your `deployment-scanner` configuration and in which file it is configured? Are you running the server in standalone mode?

Comment: Updated the answer and added the output of `/subsystem=deployment-scanner:read-resource(recursive=true)`

Comment: Once again, are you running the server in standalone mode? Are you deploying to the path _jboss.server.base.dir/deployments_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but what you want seems to be not possible to me out of the box (at the moment).
Atleast if you want to go the standard way. The standard JVM isn't capable of a full hot deploy feature yet, that's why there are products like JRebel or alternative JVM implementations or tools (HotSwap?), that may solve that problem.

See:

- [What makes hot deployment a "hard problem"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660437/what-makes-hot-deployment-a-hard-problem)
- [Change a method at runtime via a hot swap mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553353/change-a-method-at-runtime-via-a-hot-swap-mechanism)